# Number of executions of sum += 1 in a nested loop

Tags: python, big-o

So, I'm stuck with trying to figure out why the number of executions of `sum += 1` is (2n * n) in this code.

```
n = 5  # n can be anything
sum = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        sum += 1
print(sum)
```

I know for a simple loops, `sum += 1` would execute 3n times, but have no idea how to explain the math above. Thank you.

edit: Here are some pictures of the execution math, since there seems to be a confusion. Note: I'm not looking for Big(O), but the time complexity before we evaluate Big(O).
[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Comment: Why `3n` times???

Comment: And BTW, the number of iterations in your code is `n * n`, not `2n * n`.

Comment: I get 25 after correcting the indentation in your original post. 25 = 5 * 5 = n * n, not 2n * n...

Comment: Im borrowing my friend's educative account and those were the answers. My understanding is x +=1 has 3 primitive operations: variable access (x), addition ( + 1), and variable assignment. I think it's 3n times in a simple loop because sum += 1 follows the same rules of having 3 primitive operations, but is also multiplied by n, since it would iterate n times. This is before Big(O) notation. @goodvibration

Comment: But that's not how you count the number of iterations, that's how you count the number of machine operations per iteration.

Comment: I think that's Big(O) notation. I want to understand how the time complexity is 4n^3 + 2n + 3 before that. @Engineero

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new on the subject, so I'm confused. Educative has it at 3n executions before you give it the Big(O) notation. sum += 1 has 3 primitive operations under a simple loop of n times. So the number of executions should be 3n. After Big(O), it would be n times. @goodvibration

Comment: There's a loop inside a loop. The outer loop runs `n` times, and the inner loop runs `n` times for each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Oh, I think we're talking about two different things. In the original post, I was confused about  sum += 1 having a execution of 2n * n in a nested looped. I also stated that in a simple loop it's 3n executions. I get how it would execute n * n times in Big(O) notation. I'm confused about the math to get to Big(O) notation from 4n^2 + 2n + 3. @goodvibration

Comment: If you're talking about operations at the chip level, that's going to be implementation specific, although I'm willing to bet basic operations like `+=` and `for` loops are pretty optimized and there isn't a lot of variation. Still, I don't think you can be certain unless you can inspect the machine code generated from this script. I know Julia has macros to do just that, but I'm not sure about Python...

Comment: I've updated the original post with screen shots of the math

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 5  # n can be anything
sum = 0
for i in range(n): # this executes n times
    for j in range(n): # this executes n times as well
        sum += 1
print(sum)
```

This code executes in `O(n^2)` time because you multiply the first `for` loop (with `i`) that executes `n` times into the `for` loop (with `j`) which executes `n` times as well.

So n * n is how often `sum += 1` executes.

You can add a `print` statement and see for yourself. As follows:

```
from itertools import count
n = 5  # n can be anything
sum = 0
c = count()
for i in range(n): # this executes n times
    for j in range(n): # this executes n times as well
        sum += 1
        print(f'This is the {next(c)+1} execution')
print(sum)
```

Output:

```
This is the 1 execution
This is the 2 execution
This is the 3 execution
This is the 4 execution
This is the 5 execution
This is the 6 execution
This is the 7 execution
This is the 8 execution
This is the 9 execution
This is the 10 execution
This is the 11 execution
This is the 12 execution
This is the 13 execution
This is the 14 execution
This is the 15 execution
This is the 16 execution
This is the 17 execution
This is the 18 execution
This is the 19 execution
This is the 20 execution
This is the 21 execution
This is the 22 execution
This is the 23 execution
This is the 24 execution
This is the 25 execution
25
```

Comment: You are correct that the code executes O(n^2). I'm looking for the time complexity before arriving at Big(O) notation. Educative is the site I'm using, and they have the time complexity as 4n^2 + 2n + 3 before dropping everything to become O(n^2). They state line sum +=1 executes 2n * n. I don't get where the 2 comes from.

Comment: @Oka6e : If n=5 then you can see from the print statements above that that 2n * n isn't true as it executes only 25 times. I am not sure why the educative site is telling you that it executes 2n*n times but that does not hold true based on the example we have run.

Comment: They might be wrong, since I've found errors before on their site. I edited my original post with the math above.